# Need to get file path using jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor

i have a requirement where i need to get file names.

I have seen `jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.description` which returns `spec.js` description.
Similarly i need to get get `spec.js` full path. Is it possible to get file path?

Answer (score 4):

`jasmine` does not provide a reference to the file a spec is being run from. The `env` (from `getEnv()`) object only provides information on the specs and suites but not the files.

You can obtain a reference to the file's full path by utilizing the [`__filename`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_filename) global within the file itself. For example:

```
const jasmine = require('jasmine-node');
console.log(__filename);

describe('description for spec', () => {
  it('should do stuff', () => {
    console.log(jasmine.getEnv());
  });
});
```

Below's a summary of the `env` object:

```
{ currentSpec:
   { id: 0,
     env: [Circular],
     suite:
      { id: 0,
        description: 'description for spec',
        queue: [Object],
        parentSuite: null,
        env: [Circular],
        before_: [],
        after_: [],
        children_: [Object],
        suites_: [],
        specs_: [Object],
        exclusive_: 0 },
     description: 'should do stuff',
     queue:
      { env: [Circular],
        ensured: [Object],
        blocks: [Object],
        running: true,
        index: 0,
        offset: 0,
        abort: false,
        onComplete: [Function] },
     afterCallbacks: [],
     spies_: [],
     results_:
      { totalCount: 0,
        passedCount: 0,
        failedCount: 0,
        skipped: false,
        items_: [],
        description: 'should do stuff' },
     matchersClass: null,
     exclusive_: 0 },
  currentSuite: null,
  currentRunner_:
   { env: [Circular],
     queue:
      { env: [Circular],
        ensured: [Object],
        blocks: [Object],
        running: true,
        index: 0,
        offset: 0,
        abort: false,
        onComplete: [Function] },
     before_: [],
     after_: [],
     suites_: [ [Object] ] },
  reporter: { subReporters_: [ [Object] ] },
  updateInterval: 250,
  defaultTimeoutInterval: 5000,
  lastUpdate: 0,
  specFilter: [Function],
  nextSpecId_: 1,
  nextSuiteId_: 1,
  equalityTesters_: [],
  exclusive_: 0,
  matchersClass: [Function] }
```

Comment: This answer is missing information. Where does require get defined? In using this with karma, the above works when placed in the karma.conf.js, but not when placed inside a spec.js.

{
    "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer\nUncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined",
    "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer\nUncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"
  }